# Webview detect javascript errors, or url changes

Tags: ios, webview, swift3

> 

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
   override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self
        if let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com/") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }       
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("webview finished load")
        print(webView.request?.url)
    }
```

So What I need, is try to detect 1 - javascript errors. 2 - or If not, url changes. 3 or If not , can I via javascript call a function in my controller? and i call a function from my controller to javascript?

I need  a solution for an issue either way, I got problems in my webview.

Answer (score 0):

Web view can communicate with the Javascript code but the communication is limited and complicated. To answer your specific questions:

1. Javascript errors - you can detect them directly inside your webpage.
2. URL changes if successful - you can do that directly inside your webpage (`window.location = ...`).
3. View controller change on error - you can do that by changing the URL to a specific URL, e.g. `window.location = 'http://myredirect?error=Execution+failed'`. Your web view controller can easily detect the change in URL using its delegate and react accordingly.